# Underscore in table name using Spring and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I need to use a custom query for my application so this is my simplified code:

```
List<myDAO> findByName (
    String Name
);


@Query("SELECT Company, count(Name) FROM my_table GROUP BY Company")
List<myDAO> getNamesOfCustom (
    String Name
);
```

The first query works fine, the second is not, and I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: my_table is not mapped
```

I specified the table name in my DAO.
Could the problem be with the table name if the first query is working?

Comment: Specified where and how?

Comment: Maybe you need an alias in the second field `SELECT Company, count(Name)  as field_name FROM my_table GROUP BY Company`

Comment: Is the table schema different from `dbo`? Is the connection mapped to a different database?

Comment: I think you need to use the entity name rather than the table name as it seems to be a normal query, not a native SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you want a native SQL query:

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT Company, count(Name) FROM my_table GROUP BY Company", 
  nativeQuery = true)
```

Alternatively if you don't want a native query you should use the entity name, not the table name.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing